# Asp.Net Jquery not debugging

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i am trying to do a slider with jquery but i get preplex it never enters the script tag to debugg... i am puting the script tag in the layout i do not know if i am doing it right...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#slider').slider();
        });
    </script>

</head>
```

In the main page about this Pesquisa...

```
@model IEnumerable<ViveirosID.Models.Artigos>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Pesquisa";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Pesquisa</h2>

<p>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">

            Pesquisar:     <input type="text" name="nome"><br>
            <br />
            Peso:          <input type="range" name="peso" min="5" step="5" max="100">
            <br />
            Preço:         <input type="range" name="preço" min="0.5" step="0.5" max="50">
            <br />
            Descendente:   @Html.RadioButton("Ordem", "Descendente", new { ordem = "true" })
            <br />
            Ascendente:    @Html.RadioButton("Ordem", "Ascendente", new { ordem = "false" })
            <br />

            <div id="slider"></div>

            <button>Pesquisa</button>
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: Maybe there's an error preventing it from executing?  What does the browser console say?

Comment: have you included jQuery? $(document).ready requires jQuery.

Comment: yes i have and edit this question about it.... what about slider $(...).slider is not a function ????

Comment: solved... i was putting @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") in head and down in body... so it was render to times and lost connection to some library and would not have slider(...) function to use... tanks codemirror...